# sinx and sin inverse x problem

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

If $f(\sin x)=π-3x$ , find $f(x)$
My teacher says it would be $π-3sin^{-1}x$
But I believe it is wrong as in that case it would restrict the range of $f(x)$ which in this case is all real numbers

Comment: Substitute $\sin(x)\to x$ and you will get $f(x)=\pi-3\sin^{-1}(x)$ or you can include [its branches](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcSin/05/)

Comment: You and your teacher are both partially  wrong. The only thing we can say is:$$\forall x\in[-1,1],f(x)\in\pi-3\sin^{-1}(x)+2\pi\Bbb Z.$$

Comment: Note that $f(\sin x)=\pi-3x$ cannot be used as a definition of $f$ unless the range for $x$ is given over which $\sin$ is invertible. The problem is that for example $f(0)=f(\sin 0)=\pi$ and $f(0)=f(\sin \pi)=-2\pi$ cannot both be true. You could restrict yourself to for example $x\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ to get a function $f$, but if you were to take $x\in [\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ you get a different function $f$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis that's what i was also thinking , without a given domain we can't determine f(x)